# Ubuntu - Is there any programme for MD5 rainbowtables on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, hash, cryptography, md5

I've been reading about [Rainbow Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_tables) recently. There's a few webpages that will do a reverse look up for an MD5 hash. Is there any programme on Ubuntu that lets me do this? Is there something in Ubuntu that will let me generate my own rainbow tables?

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these:

[John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/)

[Rainbow Crack](http://project-rainbowcrack.com/index.htm#download)

[Ophcrack](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Generating your own tables takes a lot of computing power. Unless you have access to HPC infrastructure, you are probably better of downloading already computed tables:

http://rainbowtables.shmoo.com/